# How to add imagick extension to xamppfiles Mac M1

Tags: php, xampp, imagick

I am attempting to install imagick and use it on my php project via xampp on Mac M1, i manage to install it using below steps

```
git clone https://github.com/Imagick/imagick
cd imagick
phpize && ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And got the path of the imagick.so after building.

```
/bin/sh /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imagick/imagick/libtool --mode=install cp ./imagick.la /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imagick/imagick/modules
cp ./.libs/imagick.so /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imagick/imagick/modules/imagick.so
cp ./.libs/imagick.lai /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imagick/imagick/modules/imagick.la
```

Now i am trying to add it on my php.ini file using below methods

```
extension="imagick.so"
```

and

```
extension="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imagick/imagick/modules/imagick.so"
```

and

```
extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imagick/imagick/modules/imagick.so
```

after restarting the xampp and tried none of it worked, meaning it does not appear on my phpinfo modules and cannot instantiate `new Imagick();`  any advice